# How to adjust display of pop up date and header?

Tags: html, css, laravel

I have in trouble in edit year because the pop up is closed by header...

This is the display:

[image]

[image]

This the source code of my blade

```
<div class='input-group date' id='hrmsdate02'>
<input {{$readonly or null}} type='text' class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="Loan date" value="{{     displayhrmsDate($loan->date)}}"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
```

Comment: See if I'm right. You want to click on the year to edit it and when you click on the editor, the calendar closes. ?? Can you elaborate a bit here.

Comment: did you try to give z-index a big number like 999?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `z-index` to 20000

You page and menu may already have `z-index` greater then 2